# tap on button to take you another page error android studio

Tags: java, button

I was working in app with 2 interface.
every thing was good until i tried to put a button that take you 
to the #2 interface the app crash when i press the button in the emulator

Can someone help  explain how to do that ?

```
 Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });
```

so what is wrong?

Comment: do you have a stacktrace for us?

Comment: what is **stack_trace** ?

Comment: an exception log. I dont use Android studio but it must provides a view for it.